# Can't access my Sun X2270 Fire Server BIOS/ILOM

Tags: boot, sun

I just purchased two 2nd hand Sun X2270 Intel servers and i can't boot or access them.
They have a Service Processor installed but i don't get any signal on VGA output.

If i add an ethernet to the SP i see the cable network lights but can't access them and they don't show up in the DHCP in my (cheap AMV DSL home router). If the previous owner has set a fixed IP how can i reset the data. Reseting the CMOS did not help at all.

I have unfortunately not a Seriell <-> RJ45 cable to use the console. But why does an attached VGA and USB keyboard not work to get into the BIOS/ILOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial configuration is usually done over the serial port. In theory you can do without it but debugging any problems is done blind - you can't see if it is set to use a static address or it is trying DHCP etc.

> NET MGT port: After the initial configuration of the system using the SER MGT port,
>   communication with the SP and host is usually performed through this
>   Ethernet interface.

The [Sun Fire X2270 Server Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19432-01/820-5610-11/820-5610-11.pdf) goes over this.

More details are in the [Sun Fire™ X2270 Server Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19432-01/820-5604-11/820-5604-11.pdf).

Comment: Thanks i had to buy this serial cable. The settings was at static IP but with no IP given. Wasn't able to fix otherwise.